# How to fix bootstrap dropdown menu positioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, haml

I'm trying to implement a notifications system and the notifications dropdown button is positioned to the right of my nav bar when I click it shows the result but part of it is always out of the browser view. I didn't start this project and god knows what has been included here all I know is that my bootstrap is 4.0.0 beta

Ive tried using `.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right` bit it still remains the same

```
.dropdown{"data-behavior" => "notifications"}
  %button#dropdownMenuButton.btn.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-behavior" => "notifications-link", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
    %i.fa.fa-bell
    %span{"data-behavior" => "unread-count"}
  .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenuButton", "data-behavior" => "notification-items"}
```

Comment: this likely is happening based on other styles and containing tags, can we get the full parent tree?

Comment: How do I do that or what files do I have to show? I am very new to rails and dev in general I was hoping to only edit the .js .haml stuff so I didn't bother to learn how RoR works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer my bootstrap.css was just overwritten by another css file that had its own dropdown style